# Multiprotocol IM app that supports Yahoo Messenger "app passwords" with 2-step sign in?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

Is there any multiprotocol IM app that supports Yahoo's "App passwords" that are used after 2-step sign in is enabled?

I tried Miranda IM and Pidgin but they don't work with the app password (error: wrong password). Entering the main password (the one used to log in to the website) works but I always get this message after logging in:

> For your safety, we have temporarily disabled some features of Yahoo! Messenger. Please sign in to https://login.yahoo.com from a desktop computer, tablet, or smartphone and sign in again to Messenger to restore full access.

OS X 10.9's "Messages" app seems to work. Looking at my Yahoo account it appears that OS X uses OAuth (and the HTTP API?) to access Messenger.

Comment: They should all support it.  That is the entire point of the application password.  An individual program does not need not to specifically support it.  The should be using the application password not the your actual account's password because you have 2-factor authentication enabled.

Comment: Sadly that appears not to be the case. Even the official Windows app does not support it even though their very own help site (https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-account/SLN15241.html) seems to include "Messenger on PC" on the list of things that need an app password.

Comment: I setup 2-factor authentication on my Yahoo account, setup an application password for Yahoo IM, and proceeded to successfully log into Yahoo IM with my application password.

Comment: OK, I will try to check again with another Yahoo account.